# PHP: get image from base64 string and store it in the path

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the PHP function that adds a new data into the MySQL database.

** I want to upload the image in the web server. **

```
public function addNewCategory($category_title, $strImage) {

    // get the image from the base64 string.
    $strImage = base64_decode($strImage);
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($strImage);
    if($image !== false) {
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        imagepng($image);
        imagedestroy($image);
    }

    // set the path name of where the image is to be stored.
    $path = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/uploads/".$category_title.".png";

    // save the image in the path.
    file_put_contents($path, $image);

    // insert category and the image path into the MySQL database.
    $result = mysqli_query($this->db->connect(), "INSERT INTO category(category_title, path, created_at) VALUES ('$category_title', '$path', NOW())");

    if ($result) {
        return mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

With that function, the `path` variable is stored in the database, but the image is not actually stored in the path. What is wrong with the code above?

**Edited**
I changed the path name into `$path = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/MyProject/uploads/".$category_title.".png";`. Now the path value in the database turns out to be what I expected, but it seems like the image itself is not actually put in the path.

I added a new row to the database, manually typed the path in the browser to check if the image I sent is properly stored in the path, but the web server returns error 404.

Comment: because you're using a url, meaning you're trying to do an http UPLOAD. you can't use file_put_contents for that. it doesn't know how to handle urls for SENDING TO, only for FETCHING FROM. use a local fiesystem path, `$path = "/absolute/local/path/to/$name"`

Comment: @MarcB I edited the question. Can you please check out?

Comment: do you have a subdirectory named after your server? does `example.com//uploads/etc...` actually exist? You're simply ASSUMING that the file_put call succeeds. it returns a boolean value for a reason - CHECK IT.

Comment: @MarcB There is. I created a directory via FTP.

Comment: @MarcB If the subdirectory does not exist, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write file on server you need to set path, relative to your folder system on server. To store data in DB you need web path to your image:

```
//__DIR__ - path to your current script folder
$server_path = __DIR__."/uploads/".$category_title.".png";

// save the image in the server path.
file_put_contents($server_path, $image);

//Web path to your image
$web_path = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/uploads/".$category_title.".png";

//Write to DB web path of the image
$result = mysqli_query($this->db->connect(), "INSERT INTO category(category_title, path, created_at) VALUES ('$category_title', '$web_path', NOW())");
```

Comment: I changed the path like that, and now the result stored in the database turns out to be like `__DIR__uploads/newcategory`. Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: @newbieprogrammer what path do you need to store in db?

Comment: I want to convert the base64 string into PNG format, save this image in the path with a certain name, and store that path in the database.